# How should the structure of external API calls in an electron application be designed?

Tags: design-patterns, web-development, process

In this scenario, my renderer process' goal would be to make an HTTP request to an external web server and receive responses.

My question is: which options below would be more secure, give a future developer less headache in terms of the development process, and also be better as a general design approach (whether in case of general software or electron specifically)?

Option 1:

Currently, from the main process, I am using [utilityProcess](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/utility-process) to create the express web server (using the file path as a custom module in a fork call) as a child process. Using [MessageChannelMain](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/message-channel-main) (which is similar to [Channel Messaging API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Channel_Messaging_API)), I can communicate with the child process.

My renderer process will be initiating the request-response cycle and after the first channel with the ipcRenderer and ipcMain methods between renderer and main, there would be a second channel communication between main and the child process. Finally, another trip from child process to main to renderer occurs.

Option 2:

We would eliminate the child process web server, and use [ClientRequest](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/client-request) while trying to create a web server in the main process itself.

Option 3:

We would only use the renderer process to make API calls and connect to the external server directly.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, option 3 would likely be the most secure and straightforward approach, with the least amount of potential issues or maintenance concerns. More precisely:

- **Option 1:** While it may work, introduces additional complexity with the use of a child process and multiple communication channels. This could potentially lead to security vulnerabilities or errors if not implemented correctly. It may also be more difficult to maintain and debug in the future.
- **Option 2:** Using ClientRequest and attempting to create a web server in the main process may also introduce additional complexity and potential security vulnerabilities. It could also potentially require more resources and  cause performance issues if handling a high volume of requests.
- **Option 3:** By connecting directly from the renderer process to the external web server, you eliminate the need for additional communication channels and potential vulnerabilities that could arise from them. Additionally, this approach would likely be simpler to implement and maintain, as it eliminates the need for additional processes or server setup.